# Show that exist point $w \in \mathbb{C}$ with $w^2 \in K$ and $z \in K(w)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let K is subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ with $K=\overline{K}$. $F(k)$ is a set with all circles in complex plane with midpoint in K and radi^us equal distance between two points from K.
Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is point from intersection two different circles from F(k).Show that exist point $w \in \mathbb{C}$ with $w^2 \in K$ and $z \in  K(w)$.

So I wrote two cyrciles as: $l_1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}| (z-a)(\overline{z-a})=r^2\}, l_2=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|(z-b)(\overline{z-b})=s^2\}$,where $a,b,r^2,s^2 \in K$ and $a\neq b$. z has to be in both so I solved for $\overline{z}=\frac{r^2-s^2-a^2+b^2+\overline{a}z-\overline{b}z}{b-a}$

Then I put $\overline{z}$ to $l_1$ and got this: $z^2(\overline{a}-\overline{b})+z(r^2-s^2+b^2-a^2)-as^2-r^2b=0$. How to use now that:$K=\overline{K}$

Comment: Are you sure $K=\bar K$ is the hypothesis you want? For such $K$, $w^2\in K \implies w\in K$.

Comment: I corrected the title. Yes, $K=\overline{K} $ is assumption. I have to show existens of point w.

Comment: When you write $\overline{K}$, you mean the image of $K$ under complex conjugation ?

Comment: If this is the case, $z$ satisfies a quadratic equation with coefficients in $K$, say $az^2+bz+c=0$. Then put $w=(z+\frac{b}{2a})$ so that $z\in K(w)$ and $w^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}\in K$.

Comment: Yes, is closed under complex conjugation. I'll check this substitution.